# How to hide suggestions box in eclipse when removing text?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, settings

I'm working in Eclipse IDE and often use auto-suggestion ability.
But the problem is my computer lagging, when I trying to remove or change some text to get more proper suggestions. So difficult to understand my question, I will give you an example:

1. I'm typing something like this: `ArrayList`
2. Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or type <kbd>.</kbd> to get suggestions.
3. Then I want to change or correct my text, for example I want not `ArrayList` but `Array`, so I click <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> to remove last symbols.

When removing unnecessary symbols, suggestions are updating automaticaly after every symbol removed, causing lags and slowering my work. In some cases I remove more chars I want and that is really annoying me. Can I change behavior and force Eclipse to hide suggestions when I'm not typing but removing text?

Comment: In the old days computing of code completion proposals blocked typing. Since it is now asynchronous it should not be a problem any longer. Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: I'm using last Oxygen.1

Comment: Are you prevented from deleting characters if the content assist (Ctrl+Space) is open? I can't reproduce the problem with Oxygen.1a.

Comment: No, I'm not prevented from removing characters but my computer starting to lag when updating content after each character removed. Because of that I want to close content assist when removing symbols. I can do that by clicking cursor in other place, but it is not convenient to click every time I want correct my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no preference to automatically close the content assist on <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> (see *Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist*).

But you can press **<kbd>Esc</kbd>** every time you want **to cancel code completion** (alias content assist).

Note that without code completion no import statements are added automatically.